# How to add events after load back by XamlReader

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, file, richtextbox

I created a class Rtb which is to create a new RichTextBox, below is the constructor and list

```
public Rtb()
    {
        newRTB = new RichTextBox();
        newRTB.IsReadOnly = true;
        newRTB.MouseDoubleClick += new MouseButtonEventHandler(newRTB_MouseDoubleClick);
        reqName = "Box" + NextID.ToString();
        newRTB.Name = reqName;
    }     

List<Rtb> rtbeditor = new List<Rtb>();
```

I want to click the menu, add a BlockUIContainer, and a new richtextbox inside the container, see below

```
    private void menuReq_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BlockUIContainer newBlockUC = new BlockUIContainer();
        newBlockUC.Margin = new Thickness(50, 10, 50,10);
        Bigwin.Document.Blocks.Add(newBlockUC); //Bigwin is a big richtextbox
        rtbeditor.Add(new Rtb());
        Rtb newRichTB = new Rtb();                
        newBlockUC.Child = newRichTB.newRTB;  

    }
```

Then I save it by using XamlWriter, the problem is XamlWriter can not save event, so i have to add the event back when loading it, see below

```
private void LoadRtfFile(string path)
    {
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open);
        FlowDocument doc = XamlReader.Load(fs) as FlowDocument;
        Bigwin.Document = doc;
        fs.Close();
        foreach (var rtb in rtbeditor)
            rtb.MouseDoubleClick += req1_MouseDoubleClick; //add event to every richtextbox

    }
```

But the doubleclick event is not added by this solution, I think the last part of codes has problem. So how to add events to every created richtextbox?

Comment: sorry, now you should see Rtb

Answer (score 1):

You are subscribing to `MouseDoubleClick` on `Rtb`, not on `Rtb.newRTB`.